# MVC 4 : Postback returns a array for property of type object in my model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a model  with one of the property of type object . This property is a dynamic property and could sometime contain a string or a date or a Boolean.

I have a editor template for each type i.e boolean , string , date etc .

The problem I have is when the page is posted , the postback contains a array instead of the actual value. The first element of the array contains the actual value.

[image]

Why is the value being returned as a array ?

My model

```
     public string Description;
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Type Type{ get; set; }
    object _value;
    public object Value { get;set;}
```

statement in the view

```
   @Html.EditorFor( m => m.Value)
```

Edit : Corrected the object name from _value to Value. It was a wrong Ctrl V operation.

Edit : The HTML rendered in the browser

When the object contain a boolean value (checkbox):

```
<div>
<input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="The BoolJPY field is required." id="FurtherInformationFieldObject_Properties_1__Value" name="FurtherInformationFieldObject.Properties[1].Value" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="FurtherInformationFieldObject.Properties[1].Value" type="hidden" value="false">
```

When the object contains a string(Textbox) :

```
<div id="divStringField"><input class="text-box single-line valid" data-val="true" data-val-required="The String Field field is required." id="FurtherInformationFieldObject_Properties_2__Value" name="FurtherInformationFieldObject.Properties[2].Value" type="text" value="">        </div>
```

Edit 2 : Posting the complete model and view code.

Controller code :

```
public ActionResult Edit(string  name ="field1" )
{
    Models.DynamicData data1 = new Models.DynamicData();

    //all this comes from the database table. I am putting the value directly in field just for simplicity
    // this is exactly how I convert the value from the entity to the model
    data1.Description = "Field1 Description";
    data1.Name = "field1";
    data1.Type = typeof(string);
    data1.Value = Convert.ChangeType("MyStringValue", data1.Type);

    //similarly add few more  fields to the model collection

    return View(data1);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Models.DynamicData model)
{
    // break point here : model.Value shows a array of string instead of the edited value.
    return View(model);
}
```

View :

```
 @model SampleDynamicDataProject.Models.DynamicData

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>DynamicData</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Model.Description
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Value)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Value)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
```

}

I should explain I used object as type for Value property because  the  value could be string or bool or date ex  data1 in above controller could look like below

```
   data1.Description = "Field2 Description";
        data1.Name = "field2";
        data1.Type = typeof(bool);
        data1.Value = Convert.ChangeType("true", data1.Type); // database stores "true" as string which is converted into a boolean and stored in the object.
```

As shown in the code , my problem is in the post action for Edit , I get Value as an array even for a simple  string.
The sample project code here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3xCaeRk2IQZSTM0aHdoWEtNYW8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: This probably happens because ASP.NET MVC model binder uses arrays and indexes for binding model properties to view. Since it does not now the type of _value, it is binding view to model as it is.

Comment: What HTML does `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Value)` give you?

Comment: @emrenevayeshirazi  I have to use the object type in the model because the eventual  type of the data is decided at runtime by fetching  the type info from the database .
is there a way to make MVC behave properly ?

Comment: @Tobberoth : It gives me a  checkbox or text box using a custom editor template depending on what is the actual data in the object ( boolean value or string )

Comment: @Pat maybe you can use, TextBoxFor or custom implementation of TextBoxFor helper instead. Unlike EditorFor It should not use the arrays for keeping track of model.

Comment: post the HTML generated by `@Html.EditorFor( m => m.Value)`

Comment: @AntoJSubash : Edited the post with the html generated.

Comment: Please, explain what is stored in the database for each field, and show the code of your custom editor. You can probably solve this with an special class, a custom editor, and perhaps a custom binder, but I need more information.

Comment: @JotaBe edited post and added code for all . also gave a link to a sample project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a answer to my question at one of the other forums.

Basically the reason MVC binder is returning a array is because it does not understand what type of data/control is used in the html and the model binder fails.

I got around my issue by modifying the model to have two different property a

```
public String StringValue
public Bool BooleanValue
```

I use the StringValue field when the Type  is String , Date , Number etc.
I use the BooleanValue for  field with Type as Boolean.

Its not the cleanest approach but it will  have to do till the point I write my own custom model binder.

Thanks to bruce who answered my question here http://forums.asp.net/p/1961776/5605374.aspx?Re+MVC+4+Postback+returns+a+array+for+property+of+type+object+in+my+model
I now understand why the model binder fails.

Pasting his answer here for the benefit of others

> you need to understand how browser postback is done. on form submit a collection of name/value pairs is sent. the name is the form element name, the value is the elements value. standard url encoding is done. so for:
>     
>   the postdata is
>      foo=1&bar=true
>   note the post data is just a string with no type data. the brwser allows duplicate name, so
>     
>   the post data is:
>      foo=1&foo=true
>   when asp.net load the post data into the form collection (which is just a dictionary), it can not add the key "foo" twice, but concats the values seperated by a "," ("1,true"). the binder just treats it as a string array named foo with 2 values.
>   now we get to another browser behavior. form elements that support checked (radio and checkbox) are only include the post data if checked. this causes a problem for the mvc binder with checkbox, becuase it can not tell from the postback data if the element was not checked or not included. this is important if you are using tryupdate to apply only a subset of the model properties, becuase only a subset was rendered. to get around this, the checkbox helper renders two fields with the same name, a hidden with the value "false" and a checkbox with the value "true".